# How to switch to --node-light in Windows app without losing wallet?

Tags: light-clients, windows, backup

After figuring out how to add `geth --light` option by adding `--node-light` to windows shortcut, i'm facing a new problem - apparently switching requires to reimport the wallet, and it expects a `.json` file.

In the app menu I've found `File > Backup > Accounts` which just opens a `keystore` folder. The files in this folder are JSON but don't have .json extension. Dropping these files into the drag and drop area crashes the app.

How do I find/create the .json file that is expected?

Thanks!